# Could not compile the mapping document nhibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

Hi all Im kind of new in nhibernate, can you please help me to check if there is something wrong here? im using hbibernate + webapp mvc visual studio 2017:

```
    private void BuildConfiguration()
    {
        //error here
        Configuration.Configure(@"~\Models\hibernate.cfg.xml");

        //already tried next command with same error
        //Configuration.Configure(@"~\Models\hibernate.cfg.xml");

        Configuration.AddAssembly(GetType().Assembly);
        Configuration.AddFile(@"~\Mappings\Users.hbm.xml");
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
<session-factory>
<property name="connection.provider">
  NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">
  NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver
</property>
<property name="connection.connection_string">
  Server=(localdb)\SQLEXPRESS;database=dbtest;Integrated User ID=sa;Password=sa123;
</property>
<property name="dialect">
  NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect
</property>
```

Comment: Have you checked the `BuildAction` property of your config and mapping files? From the docs: 'If a tool like Visual Studio .NET or NAnt is used to build the assembly, then make sure that the .hbm.xml files are compiled into the assembly as Embedded Resources.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue was related to the asp .net core 2 httpcontext.current / nhibernate compatibility problem

in the

```
configuration.Configure();
configuration.AddFile();
```

i wasnt using httpcontex.current, i already tried Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session and IHttpContextAccessor but the current is still null

so i decided to move to entity framework in that project.